# Flutter check extension of entered email address

Tags: flutter

I created a TextFormField by writing code like this:

```
TextFormField(
  style: const TextStyle(
    fontFamily: "Inter Medium",
    fontSize: 20,
    decoration: TextDecoration.none,
  ),
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintStyle: const TextStyle(fontFamily: "Inter Medium"),
    prefixIcon: const IconTheme(
      data: IconThemeData(
        color: Color(0xFF7878D0),
      ),
      child: Icon(Icons.email),
    ),
    prefixIconColor: Colors.transparent,
    hintText: "name@meb.gov.tr",
    contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(18),
    filled: true,
    fillColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 233, 233, 233),
    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: const BorderSide(
        color: Color(0xFF7878D0),
        width: 1.5,
      ),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
    ),
    enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(
        color: Colors.transparent,
      ),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
        topLeft: Radius.circular(22),
        topRight: Radius.circular(22),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  maxLines: 1,
  inputFormatters: [
    new LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(50),
  ],
),
```

I am using the TextFormField on the sign up page. I only want to accept @meb.gov.tr ​​e-mail addresses. How do I query whether the entered e-mail address ends with `@meb.gov.tr`?

Thanks for help.

Comment: do you need just a method that return true if it ends with it and false if not ?

Comment: or are you talking about using it with the TextField's validator ?

Comment: @Gwhyyy Hello, yes. I only want to return true if it ends with `@meb.k12.tr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need simply to use the `endsWith` method over the `String`, like this:

```
bool checkStringEnd(String text) {      
 return text.endsWith("@meb.k12.tr");
}

print(checkStringEnd("Test@meb.k12.tr")); // true
print(checkStringEnd("Test@gmail.com")); // false    
print(checkStringEnd("siocbodusvs")); // false
```